# "Не особо считая минут" — корректно ли здесь употреблен родительный падеж?

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Из песни Ромарио:

**Мчимся в такси, не особо считая минут и рублей!**

[Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr) утверждает, что допустим и родительный, и винительный падеж, но все равно эта строчка мне не нравится. Это только мое субъективное отношение? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Если считать, что тут применен количественно-отделительный падеж, то фраза имеет права на существование

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мчимся в такси, **не особо** считая минут и рублей!

Здесь нужно использовать В.п., так как отрицание относится к наречию, а не к глаголу. Но это стихотворная речь, в этом случае  к грамматическим ошибкам относятся менее строго (надо же уложиться в размер).

Розенталь  [http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

5) Постановка прямого дополнения в форме винительного падежа обязательна в тех случаях, когда отрицание «не» стоит не при переходном глаголе, а при другом слове в предложении, например: не вполне понял задание, не очень люблю живопись, не часто читаю художественную литературу.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что падеж употреблён некорректно, поскольку *полного отрицания* (как основания для родительного падежа для того, существование чего отрицается) здесь **нет**: ввиду оговорки "не особо", имеет место грамматический эквивалент выражения "**считая, но не особо**". То есть, имеющееся отрицание относится лишь к степени действия ("особо") деепричастия, употреблённого в *утвердительной* форме. Поэтому текст и воспринимается в духе "вы хочете песен - их есть у меня".