# Корректно ли употреблен родительный падеж в песне "Без варежек"?

Tags: падежи, управление, дополнение

Из известной песни "[Без варежек](https://www.gl5.ru/valerij_sutkin_bez_varezhek.html)":

> Мчимся в такси, не особо считая минут и рублей!

Здесь дополнение стоит в родительном падеже. А у Розенталя находим:

[§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm):

> Постановка прямого дополнения в форме винительного падежа **обязательна** в тех случаях, когда отрицание «не» стоит не при переходном глаголе, а при другом слове в предложении, например: не вполне понял задание, не очень люблю живопись, не часто читаю художественную литературу

Ваши комментарии?

Comment: В заголовке надо _родительный_, наверно.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо! Исправил.

Comment: Такой вопрос был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435391/Не-особо-считая-минут-корректно-ли-здесь-употреблен-родительный-падеж?rq=1 “Не особо считая минут” — корректно ли здесь употреблен родительный падеж?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Браво! Вы всегда на страже! Спасли меня от самого себя :) Придется закрывать вопрос.